# Vertical column in Intellij Idea at arbitrary position

Tags: intellij-idea

There is a vertical line in Intellij Idea on 120th column.

Is there a way to move it some arbitrary column (I'd prefer one hundred symbols per line)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found the answer on my own.

To change the default margin go to Preferences -> CodeStyle -> General -> Right margin and enter any value you prefer.

Comment: I would also add that, to enforce this value when formatting, you should activate Settings -> Editor -> Java/Groovy/JSON -> Wrapping and Braces -> Ensure right margin is not exceeded