# How to change line width in IntelliJ (from 120 character)

Tags: intellij-idea

I was wondering how I can change the line length in IntelliJ.

Since I use a pretty high resolution, I get that line that shows 120 characters straight through the middle of the screen. Can I change it from 120 to, say, 250?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertical column in Intellij Idea at arbitrary position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206238/vertical-column-in-intellij-idea-at-arbitrary-position)

Comment: See the linked question : Preferences -> CodeStyle -> General -> Right margin

Comment: You should use that feature to improve the readability of your code. It's a good feature. I set mine to 80 characters.

Comment: Right, no need to worry about fellows with fHD who will possibly read your code in future

Answer (score 492):

#### IntelliJ IDEA 2018

**File** > **Settings...** > **Editor** > **Code Style** > **Hard wrap at**

[image: Code Style > Hard wrap at]

#### IntelliJ IDEA 2016 & 2017

**File** > **Settings...** > **Editor** > **Code Style** > **Right margin (columns):**

[image: File > Settings]

[image: Editor > Code Style > Right margin]

Comment: I would also add that, to enforce this value when formatting, you should activate Settings -> Editor -> Java/Groovy/JSON -> Wrapping and Braces -> Ensure right margin is not exceeded

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.1 Ultimate on Windows is the same.

Comment: I also like the "Wrap on typing" option. It does all the alignment for me.

Comment: It's now an option called "Hard wrap at" located in the same tab.

Comment: What about plebs that have smaller monitors(1080p, etc.) and possibly will look on your graceful long lines? Also what about Git conflicts when you need horizontal scroll in 3 windows in row?

Answer (score 82):

You can alter the "Right margin" attribute in the preferences, which can be found via

File | Settings | Project Settings | Code Style - General

> **Right Margin (columns)**    In this text box, specify the number of columns
>   to be used to display pages in the editor.

Source: [Jetbrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/general.html)

Answer (score 43):

It seems like JetBrains made some renaming and moved settings around so the accepted answer is no longer 100% valid anymore.

**Intellij 2018.3**:

`hard wrap` - IDEA will automatically wrap the line as you type, this is not what the OP was asking for

`visual guide` - just a vertical line indicating a characters limit, default is `120`

---

If you just want to change the `visual guide` from the default `120` to, let's say `80`, in my example:

[image]

Also, you can change the color or the `visual guide` by clicking on the `Foreground`:

[image]

Lastly, you can also set the `visual guide` for all file types (unless specified) here:

[image]

Answer (score 21):

It may be useful to notice that very good answers given above may not be enough. It is because of one more tick is required here:

[image]

Comment: Thats what I was looking for, Did not understand whats Hard Wrap there then. Just say page size

Comment: Doesn't seem to be there anymore in 2019.

Answer (score 18):

Be aware that need to change both location:

```
File > Settings... > Editor > Code Style > "Hard Wrap at"

and

File > Settings... > Editor > Code Style > (your language) > Wrapping and Braces > Hard wrap at
```

Answer (score 7):

I didn't understand why my this didn't work but I found out that this setting is now also under the programming language itself at:

'Editor' | 'Code Style' | < your language > | 'Wrapping and Braces' | 'Right margin (columns)'

Answer (score 7):

Open `.editorconfig` in the root of your project (or create one if you don't have any) and add:

```
max_line_length = 80
```

The IDE should pick it up immediately (works in PhpStorm, developed by the same company). As a bonus, it can be committed to GIT and will stay consistent across different editors you may be using in the future. [More info on `.editorconfig`](https://editorconfig.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Rubymine on Mac OS and hers how i set it

**RubyMine -> Preferences**

[image]

**Editor -> Coding Style**
[image]