# Fix Rider C# formatting of linebreaks for method parameter attributes

Tags: c#, code-formatting, rider

I prefer having parameter attributes stay on the same line as the parameter itself:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost()]
public async Task<ActionResult<QuoteResponse>> CreateQuoteDataOnly([FromBody] QuoteRequest request)
```

However, I can't find the settings in Rider to make that happen.

Instead I get this:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost()]
public async Task<ActionResult<QuoteResponse>> CreateQuoteDataOnly([FromBody]
    QuoteRequest request)
```

It puts a line break AFTER the `FromBody` attribute.

Image of some of my settings in Rider:
[image: Rider settings]
The docs here haven't helped me yet:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/EditorConfig_CSHARP_LineBreaksPageSchema.html

Hopefully I'm not the only one who finds this annoying, and so far my googling skills have failed me.

Comment: Your answer is probably here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355976/how-to-change-line-width-in-intellij-from-120-character

Comment: I have my line width set at 300 already, and I have the "soft wraps" turned on, but the formatter inserts a new line just after the attribute

Comment: I have same problem. Can somebody help us ?

Answer (score 3):

Increase "Place attribute section list on separate line if it is longer than" parameter value in "Line Breaks and Wrapping" tab:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9i1EY.png)