# How to have wider lines in intellij idea (reformat code with longer lines)

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea, ide

As you can see in the image, the dart reformatted in intellij idea breaks the lines to prevent having lines too wide. However, my monitor has a lot of space and thus the reformatter doesn't need to break lines too soon.

How can I adjust the number of characters or the size of a line needed for the reformatter to break the line?

[image]

Comment: Those [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355976/how-to-change-line-width-in-intellij-from-120-character/29751140) help?

Comment: @TamirAbutbul this does not affect dartfmt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IDEA uses `dartfmt` tool from the Dart SDK for `.dart` files formatting; the only option this tool has is line length, it can be configured in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | Dart, Line length**. Did you try increasing the default value (`80`)?